# Prove or disprove there exists a permutation \sigma such that the (i,\sigma(i))th minor and the (i,\sigma(i))th entry of M are both nonzero for each i

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, permutations, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be a square matrix of full rank $n$. I'm wondering if there exists a permutation $\sigma$ such that the $\left(i,\sigma(i)\right)$-th [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of $M$ and the $\left(i,\sigma(i)\right)$-th entry of $M$ are both nonzero for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

My observations: For the first row, we can find an index $j$ such that the $\left(1,j\right)$-th minor of $M$ and the $\left(1,j\right)$-th entry of $M$ are both nonzero, which is deduced from the Laplace expansion and $\operatorname{det}(M)\neq0$. Besides, the statement can work for the case of $n=2$. Now I have no idea about how to prove or disprove the whole statement. Any ideas would be appreciated so much. Thank you!

Comment: Try seeing what happens when $M$ is the identity matrix

Comment: @BenGrossmann The statement holds for an identity matrix, doesn't it?

Comment: I misread; I thought it was such that both are zero.

Comment: To your actual question, try expanding the minor using another Laplace expansion to extend the argument to $n=3$. If you can manage that, perhaps you can see how this line of reasoning can be extended for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your clue. I got stuck in the induction step because we should focus on the submatrices of size $(n-1)\times (n-1)$, however, the assumption for $(n-1)$ can only give the properties of size $(n-2)\times (n-2)$ sub-submatrices, which makes things thicky.

Comment: Never mind, this question is trickier than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This claim would be **false** due to the following ​counterexample:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the $1$st row, we have to choose the $3$rd column, since the $(1,1)$-th minor and the $(1,2)$-th entry are $0$. However, for the $3$rd row, we still have to choose the $3$rd column since the $(3,1)$-th entry and the $(3,2)$-th minor are $0$.

Thus in the case, there doesn't exist a permutation $\sigma$ such that the $(i,\sigma(i))$-th minor and $(i,\sigma(i))$-th entry are both nonzero for each $i=1,2,3$.